# Loading row values from one table as column headers in a sub table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named unduplicatedheadcount which has about 50 columns.

I want to create a sub table in which I want to include three values of a particular column of the original table.

The column name is EFFYLEV and the values are 1,2,4.

There is another column named EFYTOTLT in this table and all these three values have some particular total number stored in this column.

Now I created the sub table with the three values (1,2,4) of column EFFYLEV as three different columns and named them as EFFTLT_1,EFFTLT_2,EFFTLT_4.

Now I want each of the corresponding total numbers for the three values in EFFYLEV from the column (EFYTOTLT) to be displayed as row values for the corresponding columns in my sub table.

I tried the following query so far

```
INSERT INTO unduplicatedheadcount_final(UNITID, EFFTLT_1, EFFTLT_2, EFFTLT_4)
SELECT UNITID,
       (SELECT EFFYLEV from unduplicatedheadcount un where EFFYLEV= 1 and un.UNITID= u.UNITID),
       (SELECT EFFYLEV from unduplicatedheadcount un where EFFYLEV= 2 and un.UNITID= u.UNITID),
       (SELECT EFFYLEV from unduplicatedheadcount un where EFFYLEV= 4 and un.UNITID= u.UNITID)
FROM unduplicatedheadcount un
WHERE un.EFFYLEV = (1,2,4)
```

I know this query is wrong so thats why I need help with it. Here UNITID is a unique identifier number which is common in both the tables. I would really appreciate a solution for this

Comment: Enumerated column names are often indicative of poor design

Comment: Still I need a logic for the query

Comment: Logically, I'd fix the design first